# Find the value of $k$ so that a curve is tangent to the line

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Find the value of $k$ if the curve $y = x^2 - 2x$ is tangent to the line $y = 4x + k$

I have looked at the solution to this question and the first step is the "equate the two functions":
$ x^2 - 2x = 4x + k$

Why? How does that help solve the equation? And how can I use what I get from equating the two functions to find the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additionally, you can also solve with calculus.
Take the derivative.
$(x^2-2x)' = 2x-2$. We want the derivative to be $4$, which is the slope of the line. This happens when $2x-2 = 4$, at $x=3$.

Plugging into our quadratic:
$y=3^2-2\cdot 3 = 3$.

So we need
$y = 4\cdot 3 + k$, or $3 = 4\cdot 3 + k$. This gives $\boxed{k=-9}$.

Comment: How does $2x - 2$ tell you that the slope is 4?

Comment: The tangent line's slope is $4$ by the equation $y=4x+k$. 
The derivative, $2x-2$ tells us the slope of the tangent line at certain $x$, so the slope at $x=3$ would be $2\cdot 3 - 2=4$, which matches the slope of the line. Thus, the line intersects the parabola at $x=3$.

I do see where my explanation was confusing. I will edit

Comment: Thanks. This method is the best imo

Answer (score 1):

If you want two lines to be tangent, you only want them to touch at one point, meaning there is only one solution to:

$$x^2-2x=4x+k$$

Which simplifies to:

$$x^2-6x-k=0$$

Note that the above only has one solution if the discriminant is equal to $0$. Can you then solve for $k$?

Comment: I plugged in the k value to find the derivative of the second function which turned out to be $y = 2x - 2$...I am unsure of what to do with this expression

Comment: You won't need to use differentiation for my method. For a quadratic in the form $ax^2+bx+c$, its discriminant is defined as $b^2-4ac$. If the discriminant is equal to $0$, then the quadratic only has one real root. Can you apply this to $x^2-6x-k$ to find the value of $k$?

Comment: Will the discriminant always equal 0? Wouldn't this method not work if there were happened to be two real roots?

Comment: You want the discriminant equal to $0$ in order for the two functions to touch at the same point, thus being tangent. The discriminant of the quadratic is $36+4k$. Set this equal to $0$ and solve for $k$. This will yield a value of $k$ such that the two functions are tangent to each other.

Answer (score 1):

The important line is "if the curve $y=x^2-2x$ **is tangent** to the line $y=4x+k$".

If the line is tangent to the curve, then they will intersect at exactly one point.

You DO NOT NEED TO prove that the line IS TANGENT. You just need to show that, if the line is tangent, then $k$ must be equal to the value of $k$ that makes the equation  $x^2-2x = 4x+k$ have exactly one solution.

Answer (score 1):

When they say that a line is tangent to a curve at a point, that means at that point, f(x) for the curve and the line are equal. That is why you are told to equate the two equations. If you equate them and solve for x, you would eventually get something like this:
$$x = \sqrt{k+9} + 3$$
Then back substitute for x into any of the equations.

Answer (score 0):

It's rather simple: equating the functions yields the equation for the abscissæ of the intersection points of the parabola  and the line, and the curve  & the line are tangent if and only if this equation has a double root, i.e., as we have a quadratic equation, if and only if its (reduced) discriminant  is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

If the line $y = 4x + k$ is tangent to $y = x^2 - 2x$, then there exists some value of $x$ for which the two curves intersect; i.e., $$4x + k = x^2 - 2x.$$  This results in one condition for $x$ that depends on $k$.

The second condition is that *at this same value of* $x$, the derivative of $y = x^2 - 2x$ equals the slope of the tangent line $y = 4x + k$.  This results in the condition $$2x - 2 = 4.$$